# Integral expansion using the Watson's lemma

Tags: perturbation-theory

Given the integral:
$$I(s)=\int_{-a}^a \exp\{s \cos(t)\}dt$$
is it possible to find an expansion of $I(s)$ using the Watson's lemma?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Riccardo. I have not an answer to your question, but I would say a thing; it is a good practice when posting a question simultaneously on MSE and MO, to inform of this, so to avoid a multiplication of efforts in the case the question had already been answered elsewhere. Bye.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watson's lemma applies to integrals of the form
$$
\int_0^Te^{-st}g(t)\,dt,
$$
where $g$ satisfies certain conditions, among them being differentiable in neighbourhood of $t=0$. You could try to put $I(s)$ into that form using symmetry and the change of variables $\cos t=1-x$:
$$
I(s)=2\,e^s\int_0^{1-\cos a}e^{-sx}\,(2\,x-x^2)^{-1/2}\,dx,
$$
but $(2\,x-x^2)^{-1/2}$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

The asymptotic behaviour of $I(s)$ can be found using Lagrange's method. A reference is [Applied Asymptotic Analysis](http://books.google.es/books/about/Applied_asymptotic_analysis.html?id=xooq99A9anMC&redir_esc=y) by Peter D. Miller, chapter 3.

### Edit

It turns out that Watson's lemma can be applied to integrals of the form
$$
\int_0^Te^{-st}\,t^\sigma g(t)\,dt,\quad \sigma>-1.
$$
It can then be applied to
$$
I(s)=2\,e^s\int_0^{1-\cos a}e^{-sx}\,x^{-1/2}(2-x)^{-1/2}\,dx.
$$